# How can I simply get the powerstate from within a powershell workflow automation runbook in Azure?

Tags: azure, powershell, workflow, runbook

I have a Powershell workflow runbook that automates starting and shutting down VMs in Azure, I updated the modules in an automation account (so I could use it for other things) and it has stopped the script working. I have fixed most of the broken stuff but the bit that is not now working is obtaining the power state eg: PowerState/deallocated so that it can be shutdown/started up. Here is my code:

```
$vmFullStatus = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName test1 -Name test1 -Status
$vmStatusJson = $vmFullStatus | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100
$vmStatus = $vmStatusJson | ConvertFrom-Json
$vmStatusCode = $vmStatus.Statuses[1].code
Write-Output "     VM Status Code: $vmStatusCode"
```

The Write-Output VM Status Code is now blank in the output of the runbook, but it outputs fine in standard shell. I only have limited experiences in workflow runbooks but I believe it needs to be converted to Json so the Workflow can use it.

I think the issue may lie with the statuses as when it is converted to Json it displays:

```
"Statuses":  [
                 "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.InstanceViewStatus",
                 "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.InstanceViewStatus"
             ],
```

Which doesn't now show the PowerState. How can I get the powerstate of a vm from within a powershell workflow runbook so it can used? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have tried an inline script and it does work if you specify a vm name:

```
$vmStatusCode = InlineScript {
$vmFullStatus = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName test1 -Name test1 -Status
$vmStatusJson = $vmFullStatus | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100
$vmStatus = $vmStatusJson | ConvertFrom-Json
$vmStatus.Statuses[1].code
}
```

But it doesn't work when you pass variables:

```
$vmFullStatus = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Name $vm.Name -Status


Get-AzureRmVM : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ResourceGroupName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an 
argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
```

it needs to be run without an inline script - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

forgot to add $using:

```
$vmStatusCode = InlineScript {
                    $vmFullStatus = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $using:vm.ResourceGroupName -Name $using:vm.Name -Status
                    $vmStatusJson = $vmFullStatus | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100
                    $vmStatus = $vmStatusJson | ConvertFrom-Json
                    $vmStatus.Statuses[1].code
                    }
```

This now works!